# How to dynamically replace unreadable characters with correct ones with jQuery, JS or PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dynamic, character

I'm not sure it's even possible, but something tells me it may be. I'd appreciate expert guidance.

My WordPress-based website gets bits of dynamic content from this other site ("this day in aviation" widget):

http://www.youngeagles.com/factzone/thisday.asp

I embed that data into my site using this bit of code:

```
<div id="this_day_in_history">
<h3>This Day in Aviation History</h3>

<script src="http://www.youngeagles.com/thisday/absolutecr.asp?z=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

</div>
```

On the original site, all the characters display perfectly fine, but when they are displayed on my site, some of the quotes and a few French and Spanish characters are replaced with `<?>`.

Is there a magic line of code that would allow me to fix the look of the characters on my site?

Preferably with jQuery or JavaScript, or maybe there's a PHP solution?

I would be grateful for your suggestions!

**EDIT: the initial solution was offered as answer to this question by Adam MacDonald, but the snippet of code he generously composed needed a couple of further adjustments for my purposes. The final solution was offered by Phoenix in a separate thread:** [A bit of PHP code wipes out WordPress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336409/a-bit-of-php-code-wipes-out-wordpress-site)

Comment: There is no silver bullet, sorry. Your site is probably using a different character encoding - see this for a start: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html (You can convert between encodings, but you need to do this when you're pulling the content, else it will be the `<?>` mess you describe.)

Comment: What kind of characters? Do you mean like smilies or alphabets from non-English languages? Explain more.

Comment: @Piskvor: thank you. I tried to replace UTF-8 with iso-8859-1 in the head of the page, the characters still do not display. You mentioned I should convert between encoding dynamically, could you explain how this can be done? @afaolek: not smiles, just quotation marks and a few French / Spanish characters with accents etc. I would be happy if I just managed to display the quotation marks correctly.

Comment: Well, depends on how exactly you extract the content, and how you insert it in your page. Best not to mess with char encoding, but use  higher level platform functionality.

Comment: @amadeus, please take a look at the edited question. I'd appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried charset="iso-8859-1" on the script tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find using iconv works the best in php .. something like:

iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $str)

It attempts to match the character to the best of its ability, and if not, drops it

Also, utf8_encode/decode sometimes works fine.

EDIT:

perhaps something like this ...

```
    <?php
    $contents=file_get_contents('http://www.youngeagles.com/thisday/absolutecr.asp?z=1');
    $convertedcontents=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $contents);
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".$convertedcontents."</script>";
    ?>
```

EDIT 2:
just in case you want to see the changes in place of your current code:

```
    <div id="this_day_in_history">
    <h3>This Day in Aviation History</h3>
    <?php
    $contents=file_get_contents('http://www.youngeagles.com/thisday/absolutecr.asp?z=1');
    $convertedcontents=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $contents);
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".$convertedcontents."</script>";
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Adam! This looks very promising! May I please ask you to show my exactly how to use this with my code? (You're dealing with an amateur web developer.)

Comment: This code looks great Adam, thank you. Unfortunately, when I insert it into the post in WordPress, the page outputs the code itself - even though I do it in the HTML editing mode. You wouldn't happen to know how to insert your code inside WordPress post to make it work?

Comment: Dimitri, I have a couple things to take care of and then can check this out for you, I know PHP can be used in wordpress, but not exactly sure how .. did a quick search, and this may help you .. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-php-inside-a-custom-page .. if it does, keep me posted, else I'll help in a couple hours

Comment: Thank you Adam. Please forgive my disappearing for over two days, I was away from my computer. I inserted your snippet using a WordPress plugin. The code works great in Safari, but for some reason wipes out the entire page in Firefox and Chrome (only the incoming text is shown on a white page, and nothing else). I tested the WordPress plugin with some other PHP code, and the page is displayed OK, so the problem has to be in your code. Could you please help me to fix it? I would be grateful!

Comment: P.S. I also tried your code using a different WordPress "php in page" plugin, and the entire page is wiped out again in Firefox and Chrome. The source code page is completely blank! Would appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to incompatible encoding used by your site and the site you are getting the data from. It could also be that the widget gets the data and does an UTF8 encodeing/decoding on it. What I would do is probably to install firebug, check the data returned. Then I would edit the widget code and add a `utf8_encode()` or a `utf8_decode()`on the response as needed.

edit: Also, check that there doesn't exist a flag you can send when you request the data that indicates the encoding you want the answer in. I have seen this used before where you could tell the service to return the data in UTF8 or not.

Comment: Thank you inquam! Could you please show me how to use this code in my specific situation? (I'm an incurable beginner.)

Comment: Since I don't use the widget myself I do not know how it's code looks and where the fix should be implemented.
My installation is in Swedish, but i think that under **Widgets/Edit** or something similar you can select the widget you whish to edit and edit the source code for it.