# A bit of PHP code wipes out WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm loading data dynamically into a WordPress site:

http://cybart.com/cywp/

- from another site:

http://youngeagles.com/factzone/thisday.asp

To do that, I insert this bit of code into the WordPress page:

```
<div id="this_day_in_history">
    <h3>This Day in Aviation History</h3>
    <?php
    $contents=file_get_contents('http://www.youngeagles.com/thisday/absolutecr.asp?z=1');
    $convertedcontents=iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $contents);
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".$convertedcontents."</script>";
    ?>
    </div>
```

For some reason, this snippet of PHP code wipes out the entire page, leaving it blank and displaying only the data it loads. The effect seems to occur only in Firefox and Chrome; in Safari and IE I can see the website just fine.

I would appreciate someone's expert advice on this.

Comment: i think the whole contents are getting ignored. try removing ignore and test. Also note The iconv() stops at the first illegar char, cutting off the string right there, which is the default behaviour of iconv()

Comment: You're not only loading file content, but you're actually loading a script from a remote server... Sounds eerie..

Comment: What's in that `$convertedcontents` variable?  Must be something that's causing the parsers to blow a fuse. Given it's being output into a script block, possibly the iconv and/or raw contents are causing a parse error of some sort. Check FF's javascript console (shift-ctrl-J) for JS errors.

Comment: the converted file probably has a close </script> tag and everything after that would get rendered as HTML

Comment: @LDG, I get this error message in Firefox: Error: attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
Source File: http://cybart.com/cywp/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4
Line: 113

Comment: @G molvi: tried removing ignore. Same result.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I used this scipt initially, and everything worked fine, except some characters didn't display properly. <div id="this_day_in_history">
<h3>This Day in Aviation History</h3>
<script src="http://www.youngeagles.com/thisday/absolutecr.asp?z=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are fetching contains a call to `document.write()`, which will erase all the content if it is called after the page is finished loading:

```
document.write("\n<P>...<\/P>");
```

See the notes on the [MDC page for document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write) for more information.

You might need to parse the code from http://www.youngeagles.com/thisday/absolutecr.asp?z=1 manually, e.g.:

```
<div id="this_day_in_history">
<h3>This Day in Aviation History</h3>
<?php
$contents=file_get_contents('http://www.youngeagles.com/thisday/absolutecr.asp?z=1');
$convertedcontents=iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $contents);

if( preg_match('#^document\.write\("(.+)"\);$#s', $convertedcontents, $matches) )
{
  echo stripslashes(str_replace('\\n', '', $matches[1]));
}
else
{
  // TODO Format of $convertedcontents has changed.  Log for developer review.
}
?>
</div>
```

Note that you'll need to use the [`s` pattern modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers), as the string you are trying to match has newline characters in it.

Comment: Thank you Phoenix, I think you're right - but how come this code only erases the page if used inside the PHP code? When I used it like this: <div id="this_day_in_history"> <h3>This Day in Aviation History</h3> <script src="youngeagles.com/thisday/absolutecr.asp?z=1"; type="text/javascript"></script> </div> – it didn't erase the page.

Comment: Sorry Phoenix, what would the complete bit of code look like, including the code that loads the data and translates it into a different encoding? (I'm a newbie.)

Comment: OK Phoenix, great! - it doesn't wipe out the site, but it displays this, instead of text: “\n

June 13, 1916<\/FONT><\/STRONG><\/P>\n

The Zeppelin-Lindau Dornier Rs II hydroplane, piloted by Schröter and Schulte, succeeds in taking off from Lake Constance, Germany, and makes a four-minute flight. <\/SPAN><\/P><\/FONT>” – We're definitely on the right track though. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Good thing I was paying attention when I tested it :P  I've added code to exclude the quotes from the match, strip slashes and convert `\n` characters to `<br />`.

Comment: LOL, argh! Almost there, Phoenix. But now I get lots of "n" and a little to many breaks between the lines.  (Originally it didn't have spaces between paragraphs that wide.) Please be my savior and help me to make it work!

Comment: Interesting.  Ok, let's try removing `\n` instead.

Comment: YES! IT WORKS! YOU'RE # 1 Phoenix!